# setonclicklistener effect every 4th position in recycler view

Tags: java, android

```
/**
 * Created by Prateek on 2/18/2017.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import newsee.novasyslabs.com.nodefetch.Others.CircularTransform;

import com.squareup.picasso.MemoryPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    public static ArrayList <String> embed_html = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList <String>  channel_thumbnail = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList <String> channel_title = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList <String> video_title = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList <String> created_time = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList <Integer> android_likes = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList <Integer> pf_likes = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList <Integer> android_views = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList <Integer> pf_views = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        WebView webView;
        public ImageView chlogo;
        public TextView chtitle;
        public TextView vidtitle;
        public TextView upld_time;
        public TextView show_views;
        public TextView show_likes;
        public ImageView mLike;
        int j = 0;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mLike = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_like);
            this.show_views = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_views_count);
            this.show_likes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes_count);
            this.webView = (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.web);
            this.chlogo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ch_logo);
            this.chtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ch_name);
            this.vidtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
            this.upld_time = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ch_time);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_card, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.mLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (holder.j==0) {
                    holder.mLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.liked);
                    CharSequence like = holder.show_likes.getText();
                    int new_like = Integer.parseInt((String) like) + 1;
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Liked" +new_like ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.j = 1;
                } else {
                    holder.mLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlike);
                    CharSequence like = holder.show_likes.getText();
                    int new_like = Integer.parseInt((String) like) - 1;
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Unliked" +new_like,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.j = 0;
                }
            }
        });

            holder.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            holder.webView.loadData(embed_html.get(position), "text/html", "utf-8");
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(channel_thumbnail.get(position)).transform(new CircularTransform()).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).into(holder.chlogo);
            holder.chtitle.setText(channel_title.get(position));
            holder.vidtitle.setText(video_title.get(position));
            holder.upld_time.setText(created_time.get(position));
            int and_views = android_views.get(position);
            int views = pf_views.get(position);
            views += and_views;
            int and_likes = android_likes.get(position);
            int likes = pf_likes.get(position);
            likes += and_likes;
            holder.show_views.setText("" + views);
            holder.show_likes.setText("" + likes);


        }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return embed_html.size();
    }
}
```

when i am clicking then image change for 0th postion then 4,8,12.... why onclicklistener effect every 4 object in recyclerview i am changing the image resource onClick but the images changes for 4postion, 8position

Comment: Recyclerview recycles the view everytime, so that means your screen layout refreshes everytime you scroll

Comment: post your full adapter class

Comment: Make your position parameter final on onBindView of Adapter Method  will do job for you..

Comment: Posted an answer for you, check if it helps

Comment: postion is already final on onBindView of Adapter Method. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing it this way, first in your onBindViewHolder method add this code:

```
holder.mLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showImage(position);
            }
        }
    });
```

Then create a new method in this class only:

```
public void showImage(int position){
if (position == 0) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.medal);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I made changes as you said but it's not working. problem is remain same

Comment: @Prateek218 can you post your adapter class. I'll check

Comment: now i have posted my adapter class. Please see to it thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you got any solution

Comment: Will post as soon as I'll get one